# Drawing a hypergraph in latex

Tags: pstricks, tikz-cd

I need to draw following hypergraph in Latex.
[image]

My attempt-

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{pstricks}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{pst-grad} % For gradients
\usepackage{pst-plot} % For axes
\usepackage[space]{grffile} % For spaces in paths
\usepackage{etoolbox} % For spaces in paths
\makeatletter % For spaces in paths
\patchcmd\Gread@eps{\@inputcheck#1 }{\@inputcheck"#1"\relax}{}{}
\makeatother 

\begin{figure}[t]

\begin{center}

\psscalebox{0.5 0.5} % Change this value to rescale the drawing.
{
\begin{pspicture}(0,-5.677559)(12.57659,2.6669903)
\psrotate(2.7260337, 0.3329967){-38.651867}{\psellipse[linecolor=black, linewidth=0.04, dimen=outer](2.7260337,0.33299673)(3.3083334,1.3883333)}
\psrotate(1.1277003, 1.5757744){7.4958577}{\psdots[linecolor=black, dotsize=0.8378179](1.1277003,1.5757744)}
\psdots[linecolor=black, dotsize=0.8](2.585478,0.40244114)
\psdots[linecolor=black, dotsize=0.8](4.1499224,-0.8420033)
\psellipse[linecolor=black, linewidth=0.04, dimen=outer](6.994367,-0.80867)(3.6977777,1.2588888)
\psdots[linecolor=black, dotsize=0.8](6.8521447,-0.7708922)
\psdots[linecolor=black, dotsize=0.8](9.056589,-0.69978106)
\psellipse[linecolor=black, linewidth=0.04, dimen=outer](6.9232564,-2.6731143)(1.2444445,3.0044444)
\psdots[linecolor=black, dotsize=0.8](6.745478,-2.619781)
\psdots[linecolor=black, dotsize=0.8](6.7810335,-4.1131144)
\psellipse[linecolor=black, linewidth=0.04, dimen=outer](9.234367,-4.2197814)(3.3422222,1.0311111)
\psdots[linecolor=black, dotsize=0.8](9.234367,-4.219781)
\psdots[linecolor=black, dotsize=0.8](11.225478,-4.219781)
\end{pspicture}
}
\end{center}
\label{dot}
\end{figure}
```

however it does not give any result. If possible can anyone explain or give a sample code? I am ok with tikz too.

Comment: I obtain a result compiling with `xelatex`  but the upper-leftmost dot is not where it should be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome to TeX.SE!!!

This can be easily done in Ti*k*Z defining a `\pic` for the ellipse with the three dots. We can add a parameter which shifts the `\pic` to one dot or another, and then the positioning is very simple.

Something like this:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}

\tikzset
{%
  pics/my ellipse/.style={% #1 --> shift to node (1,2,3)
      code={%
          \begin{scope}[shift={(1.5*#1-3,0)}]
            \draw (0,0) ellipse (2.5cm and 0.75cm);
            \foreach\i in {1,2,3}
              \fill (1.5*\i-3,0) circle  (0.5) node (-\i) {};
            \end{scope}
    }},
  pics/my ellipse/.default={2},
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pic             (A) at (0,0) {my ellipse};
\pic[rotate= 90] (B) at (A-2) {my ellipse=1};
\pic             (C) at (B-1) {my ellipse=3};
\pic[rotate=300] (D) at (A-1) {my ellipse=1};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Fabulous also this LOL :-)

Answer (score 2):

run with lualatex to get directly the pdf:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{pstricks}

\def\EllipseAndDots(#1)#2{%
  \rput{#2}(#1){\psellipse(0,0)(2.75,1)\psdots[dotsize=0.8](-1.5,0)(0,0)(1.5,0)}}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=false](2,-5)(11.5,2.5)
\EllipseAndDots(7,-0.75){0}%
\EllipseAndDots(7,-2.25){90}%
\EllipseAndDots(8.5,-3.75){0}%
\EllipseAndDots(4.44,0.31){135}%
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

or with easier coordinates:

```
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=true](-5,-5)(5,3)
\EllipseAndDots(0,0){0}%
\EllipseAndDots(0,-1.5){90}%
\EllipseAndDots(1.5,-3){0}%
\EllipseAndDots(-2.56,1.06){135}%
\end{pspicture}
```

`1.06 = 0.75*sqrt(2)`   (cosinus)

[image]